# How to export Keras h5 format to TensorFlow .meta?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I used Keras to build a model and trained it. Then I saved the model as an `h5` file, i.e. `model.save('name.h5')`. Now I want to reload the model in tensorflow such that I have access to `.meta` file, for example I want to import the computational graph from the `.meta` file, i.e., `tf.train.import_meta_graph('name_of_the_file.meta')`.

So, the question is how to convert `.h5` file of Keras to the following four files of TensorFlow:

1. `.meta`
2. `checkpoint`
3. `.data-00000-of-00001`
4. `.index`

Comment: did the answer work?

Answer (score 0):

You can use 3rd party packages, for example [keras_to_tensorflow](https://github.com/amir-abdi/keras_to_tensorflow)

> keras_to_tensorflow: General code to convert a trained keras model into an inference tensorflow model

The conversion can be done by

```
python3 keras_to_tensorflow.py -input_model_file model.h5
```

Comment: you also need -output_model parameter

Answer (score 0):

Tensorflow 2.x will do that automatically. The function you are using to [save](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#save) (see [also](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/models/save_model)) is:

```
save(
    filepath,
    overwrite=True,
    include_optimizer=True,
    save_format=None
)
```

The save format let's you choose either 'h5' or 'tf'. However, for tensorflow 1.x is not implemented yet (and probably never will).

> `save_format`: Either 'tf' or 'h5', indicating whether to save the model
>   to Tensorflow SavedModel or HDF5. The default is currently 'h5', but
>   will switch to 'tf' in TensorFlow 2.0. The 'tf' option is currently
>   disabled (use `tf.keras.experimental.export_saved_model` instead).

You can do as it says and use the `tf.keras.experimental.export_saved_model` but it will still not create the `.meta` file.